# Управление ориентацией через css

Tags: css, css3

Возможно ли при помощи css, добавить класс в блок к примеру в body добавляем класс landscape, и делаем альбомную ориентацию и как бы блокируем ее до того времени пока пользователь не удалить это самый класс.

Answer (score 2):

Добавление классов, да и вообще манипулированием `DOM` деревом это исключительно прерогатива `JS`, но имеються решения при помощи медиавыражений. Экран они не блокируют, но идея вроде понятна.

```css
@media (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  body {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  body:after {
    content: "Переверни экран телефона";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
  }

}
```

А вообще вот, неплохая [подборочка сниппетов](https://snipplr.com/view/67341).